# JSON field is string containing JSON; how do I convert that to proper JSON?

Tags: python, json

While converting a CSV file to JSON i am getting output like below:

```
 {
        "id": "8835435",
        "userid": "1111",
        "key": "diary_notifications",
        "setting": "{\n  \"standup_reminder\" : false,\n  \"weight_reminder_diary\" : true,\n  \"weight_reminder_notification\" : false,\n  \"meal_reminders_lunch\" : false,\n  \"meal_reminders_breakfast\" : false,\n  \"meal_reminders_snack\" : false,\n  \"weight_reminder_calendar\" : false,\n  \"weight_reminder_time\" : false,\n  \"meal_reminders_dinner\" : false,\n  \"water_reminders\" : false,\n  \"walking_reminder\" : false,\n  \"sleep_reminder\" : false\n}",
        "lastupdated": "2018-03-27 10:48:51",
        "creatd": "2014-11-13 15:47:23"
    }
```

How can I remove the newline characters from `setting` and convert the field to a proper list in Python code? My code is:

```
import csv
import json

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append({"id":row[0],"userid":row[1],"key":row[2],"setting":row[3],"lastupdated":row[4],"creatd":row[5]})
with open ("users.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(data,f,indent=4)
```

What needs to be added above?

Comment: Use df to read csv and then json.dump(df) to convert into proper json format 

Comment: Can you post a few rows of the CSV

Comment: @RahulShukla: the question is not tagged with pandas, and pandas would be overkill here. Moreover, you proposal does not address OP's question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setting` field contains a Json string, so you should just parse it with the `json` module. Of course in only some lines contain a Json string and others only contain a plain one, you should *protect* the `json.loads` in a `try` block:

```
import csv
import json
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        try:
            row[3] = json.loads(row[3])
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            pass
        data.append({"id":row[0],"userid":row[1],"key":row[2],"setting":row[3],
         "lastupdated":row[4],"creatd":row[5]})
with open ("users.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(data,f,indent=4)
```

It should give (more or less):

```
{
    "id": "8835435",
    "userid": "1111",
    "key": "diary_notifications",
    "setting": {
        "standup_reminder": false,
        "weight_reminder_diary": true,
        "weight_reminder_notification": false,
        "meal_reminders_lunch": false,
        "meal_reminders_breakfast": false,
        "meal_reminders_snack": false,
        "weight_reminder_calendar": false,
        "weight_reminder_time": false,
        "meal_reminders_dinner": false,
        "water_reminders": false,
        "walking_reminder": false,
        "sleep_reminder": false
    },
    "lastupdated": "2018-03-27 10:48:51",
    "creatd": "2014-11-13 15:47:23"
}
```

Comment: getting this error JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). Is anything need to changed here:"setting":json.loads(row[3])

Comment: Please show your csv file **as text**. I tried to build one from your example and got no error but...

Comment: id userid key setting lastupdated created
5267840 1111 activation "{
  """" : ""2015-08-21"",
  ""food_rating_trial"" : ""2015-08-27"",
  ""diets"" : true,
  ""date"" : ""2014-07-24"",
  ""app_starts"" : 2,
  ""partners"" : true,
  ""recipe_date"" : ""2015-06-24""
}" 27/08/2015 10:13 14/07/2014 15:00
12 1111 brand_change YES 02/12/2013

Comment: Cannot paste more data as size limit.  Any suggestion.

Comment: @turitiw: the suggestion is that data should have been an edit to the question. It is much more easy to write formatted data in a question than in a comment :-) . Anyway the second line was enough to give me a hint.

Comment: thanks @Serge Ballesta for all your effort.